# Redirect or render another view on event

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm building a little CRUD app in Backbone, and I'm stuck a little with a need to redirect from one view to another. My app consists of a `layout` view, in which other views are rendered, and a router. Here it is:

```
var router = Backbone.Router.extend({
     routes: {
         '': 'home',
         'resumes/:id': 'showResume'
     },

     home: function () {
         // renders a index view with my collection
         this.layout.render(new ResumeList({collection: resumes});
     },
     showResume: function () {
         if (!this.fullResume) {
             this.fullResume = new FullResume({model: new Resume()});
         }
         // allowing to navigate via url with model id
         this.fullResume.model.set('id', id).fetch({
             context: this,
             success: function () {
                 this.layout.render(this.fullResume);
             }
         });
     }
});
```

Then, in my `FullResume` view I've got a `delete` event, which destroys the model. Here it goes:

```
var FullResume = Backbone.View.extend({
    // tagName and other stuff
    events: {
        // other events
        'click #delete': 'deleteResume'
    },
    // initialize, render and other functions
    deleteResume: function () {
        this.model.destroy({
            success: function (res) {
                console.log('DELETE model' + res.toJSON().id);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('Failed to DELETE');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The function above works perfectly and deletes the model, but after deleting the model it still remains on it's view until I navigate somewhere manually. I read a bit and tried to manage how to render the main view after this event or redirecting to it, but didn't succeed a much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate function with the `trigger` option set to true.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/x3t7u5p0/

Clicking on "Home" or "About" links will change the view, however I've added a delayed programmatic view change, when the About view renders, it will switch back to Home after the delay

```
  render: function () {
      this.$el.html(this.template);
      _.delay(function() {
          appRouter.navigate('home', {trigger: true});
      }, 500);
  }
```

Comment: if your router is not shared across your code, you can navigate directly using `Backbone.history.navigate(...)`.